# how to put item cheked in a listview?

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview , i would like to put some position preselected; in fact i have some values that i would like to put them selected. this is my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
                // Item position in adapter
                int position = checked.keyAt(i);
                // Add sport if it is checked i.e.) == TRUE!
                if (checked.valueAt(i)) {
                    selectedItems.add(adapter.getItem(position));
                }
            }

            String[] outputStrArr = new String[selectedItems.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
                outputStrArr[i] = selectedItems.get(i);
            }
```

My `selectedItems`  firstly is not empty; i would like to put its value as selected.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your `selectedItem` list to your `custom adapter` and inside `getView()` method compare `position`. If it is available in `seloectedItem` list change the `background` of `view`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom adapter and pass the list inside there and render it on getView() by inflating the item.xml layout and use a static class viewHolder to create a viewholder that transfers the data from your list into the appropriate widgets.

Make sure you check if the convertView has been created previously as you do not want to create the view every time android hits getView from your adapter as it will slow your listView UI.

Good luck